# access MONGODB on remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

i am a newbie.. i know coding language such as python and mongodb(pymongo).. 
Now i want to make a web based ui to get and display records on the client pc.. there maybe some queries the client enters to get desired records... 
the mongodb is on a server... I need to know what tools are there that i will require to send the queries and also to query the db on the server.. 
I ggoled and found node.js ,rest etc.. but couldn't understand exactly... pls help me to understand exactly what things i will need to see to help me build it...

Comment: Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431912/access-mongodb-on-remote-server/41432967#41432967) below help you? If so then you can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157646).

Comment: sorry. i am new to the community..  i have basically stored a mongodb database in a server.. i now want to develop some backend script or program so that i can enter the url in any webbrowser .. a page should open asking for the idno of a record(this is unique).. now i want to access the mongodb,  get the record and display it in the webbrowser... i dont know javascript .. but i know python and c++ and java quite good.. so anybody can show me what should i use for quickstart.. thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a backend API that will be used by your frontend/desktop application. The technology you use is up to you - it can be Node, Python, Ruby, Java, Go, Lua, Perl or even C.

If you use Node then you can use Express, if you use Python then you can use Django, if you use Ruby then you can use Rails, if you use Perl then you can use Catalyst etc. so when you choose your language and runtime then you will have to choose a backend framework to write the API because you don't want to do it from scratch especially if you don't have experience with that.

If you choose Node then LoopBack is relatively easy to quickly build a RESTful API to access the database. But there is also Hapi, Restify, Sails, Koa, Express and much more.

That backend would have to connect to the database because it is never a good idea to connect to your database directly from an application on the user's computer for security reasons.

This is not a question that anyone will be able to answer in more details. There are a lot of technologies to understand to build what you need. You will need some time to gain experience needed to do what you describe but here are the main concepts to get familiar with: backend languages and runtimes, backend frameworks, API architectures, REST, HTTP, Mongo drivers, queries, abstractions, data models, routes, endpoints, handlers, controllers etc. Good luck.